# Dialog inside a overlaypanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I have this code:

```
<p:overlayPanel id="advancedSearchPanel" styleClass="ui-advanced-search-overlay" for="advancedSearch" hideEffect="fade" my="right top" dismissable="false">

<h:form>

<h:panelGrid>

....

<p:commandButton id="btnOpenTree" value="Lista classificadores" onclick="dlg1.show();" /> 

...

</h:panelGrid> 

<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg1">
                <p:tree id="treeClassifier" value="#{searchForm.rootClassifier}" var="node" selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{searchForm.selectedClassifiers}" style="height: 200px;width: 70%;overflow: auto; float: right;">
                    <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
                        <h:outputText value="#{node.description}"/> 
                    </p:treeNode> 
                </p:tree>
           </p:dialog>

</h:form>

</p:overlaypanel>
```

I try to call the dialog when clicking on the button btnOpenTree, but when i click on this component the overlaypanel is closed and the dialog never appears. I try to put the dialog outside the form body but nothing happens. Any idea why i cannot display de dialog?